# Using the same key that aspnet_regiis uses to encrypt the web.config to encrypt data programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I recently discovered the ability to use aspnet_regiis to encrypt portions of the web.config. We want to further encrypt the data stored in the database with a separate key but store that key encrypted using the same key the system used to encrypt the web.config. Is there a way to access that programmatically from within C#/ASP.Net itself?

Basically, the scenario is: Our connection string in web.config will be encrypted using aspnet_regiis (currently RSA provider until I can get the AES provider to work). Then we want additional connection string information (for other databases) stored in that initial database (including a writable connection for the initial database) stored that is encrypted with a different key, but that key will be stored in the initial database and encrypted using the initial encryption that the web.config used.

Otherwise I will have to store a key and IV for the algorithm used in the web.config, and I'd think that it would be more secure to use the windows security "keychain" that it used to encrypt the web.config in the first place.

Comment: Using an RSA private key that you don't own is rarely a desirable practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure that you can get at the encryption key used by aspnet_setreg.

Second, I do not think that encrypting data in a database using a machine-specific key is a terribly good idea. What happens to the data in the database if that machine goes down and the database has to be restored from backup to a different machine?

I think you would be much better off using a reversible encryption algorithm (i.e. Rinjadel) using a key and iv that is stored in a compiled application that is used to extract the data.

If other apps need the connection strings, you could centralize access to them through a WCF service using windows security credentials.